# "Remember this approval" when using dotNetOpenAuth and Google Apps doesn't work as expected

Tags: oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth, google-apps

I'm using dotNetOpenAuth to provide SSO to my app via a user's Google Apps account. Besides just simple authentication I also ask Google to return the user's email, first name and last name.  When a user first goes in they get redirected to the typical Google Accounts page telling them that the app is asking for this info and do they want to allow it.  There is the checkbox there to Remember This Approval.  The problem is, the approval isn't being remembered.  It does remember them if they go back to the site without closing their browser.  But if they close their browser and then open it later and go back in, they are again prompted to allow it.

If I look through my Google account page that shows me connected sites, apps, and services, I see my app listed multiple times. It's like it doesn't recognize that it's the same app and keeps adding it.

I know I must be missing something obvious, but I'm not sure what it is.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

You can find my code [here](https://github.com/fynydd/googauth/)

Answer (score 4):

I see several problems in your code.  To first answer your direct question, the reason Google doesn't remember you on return visits is because you are passing a random GUID in as part of your Realm each time you log in.  The symptom is actually much worse than you realize.  It's not just that Google prompts the user on return visits, *your site won't recognize the user at all on return visits* because Google will give them a *new* claimed identifier on each visit.

The fix is that you should use the exact same Realm for every login request:

```
Realm realm = "http://www.yoursite.com/";
var req = openid.CreateRequest(discoveryUri, realm, URIbuilder.Uri );
```

Or my personal favorite:

```
var req = openid.CreateRequest(discoveryUri, Realm.AutoDetect, URIbuilder.Uri );
```

`Realm.AutoDetect` will work for you unless your site is available *both* via HTTP and HTTPS, in which case you need to lock it down to just one or the other of these so that Google recognizes your site as always the same.

You must also remember that the returnTo URL that you pass in as the 3rd parameter to `CreateRequest` must always be based on the realm.  So if your realm is HTTPS, so must your returnTo parameter be.

I also want to call out that you seem to have some GUID code and complex URL manipulation around trying to ensure that every OpenID response you accept comes from a request you sent out.  I'm not sure why you're trying to do this in the first place, although there certainly can be legitimate reasons.  The way you did it is insecure and can be circumvented.  I suggest you delete all this code, in favor of adding this to your web.config file:

```
<dotNetOpenAuth>
    <openid>
        <relyingParty>
            <security rejectUnsolicitedAssertions="true" />
        </relyingParty>
    </openid>
</dotNetOpenAuth>
```

The library has support for requiring all responses to come from your requests built in, and it does so securely so that the security exploit I alluded to earlier isn't possible.

But if you're only trying to apply this restriction so that you know it's coming from Google, may I recommend that instead of rejecting unsolicited assertions, you instead check the `IAuthenticationResponse.Provider.Uri` property when you receive responses and verify that it is coming from the Google OP Endpoint?  Then, if Google ever supported sending unsolicited assertions it would work on your site, and ultimately your security gate is exactly where you intended it to be anyway.